# Help with CSS Positioning

Tags: css, html

I am trying to position an image over the background image, but the image will not show up. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="twitter">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
background: url(...) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

twitter {
    background: url(...) no-repeat;
    //top:10px;
    //position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that stands out is that you need hashes in front of your identifiers in your CSS...

```
#body {
background: url(...) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

#twitter {
    background: url(...) no-repeat;
    //top:10px;
    //position: absolute;
}
```

I would also recommend using a different name from "body" on the outermost div to avoid confusion with the `<body>` html tag. Its not strictly necessary, but it helps to have less to think about.

For CSS:

- if you want to reference elements by id="", you prefix your CSS rule identifier with a "#" , e.g. `#twitter { .... }`
- if you want to reference elements by class="", you prefix your CSS rule identifier with a "." , e.g. `.twitter { .... }`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put `.twitter` as a class or `#twitter` as an id rather than `twitter` (as in a tag).

Answer (score 0):

yes, as said above you need to put a `#` when referring to IDs in CSS, but you also need to specify a `width` and a `height` for your `#twitter` div, so that is will have some dimension.